# How to pass the element's ID as an argument to a function which uses getElementById?

Tags: javascript

I wrote this code for a testing purpose. I have some divs set with `display:none` in my HTML file. I wrote a script to get the content of those divs and assign them to another div. As the script is, right now, it works, but I would like to know a way to write the "loadcontent" functions as a single function. Here is the code :

```
'use strict';
var gameWorld = {
    contentoutput: document.getElementById("contentoutput"),
    linkhome : document.getElementById("linkhome"),
    linkshop : document.getElementById("linkshop"),
    linkupgrade : document.getElementById("linkupgrade"),
    linkachievement : document.getElementById("linkachievement"),


    addEventHandlers : function() {
        linkhome.addEventListener("click", loadcontent1);
        linkshop.addEventListener("click", loadcontent2);
        linkupgrade.addEventListener("click", loadcontent3);
        linkachievement.addEventListener("click", loadcontent4);
     }
}

function loadcontent1 () {
var x = document.getElementById("contenthome").innerHTML;
contentoutput.innerHTML = x;
};function loadcontent2 () {
var x = document.getElementById("contentshop").innerHTML;
contentoutput.innerHTML = x;
};function loadcontent3 () {
var x = document.getElementById("contentupgrade").innerHTML;
contentoutput.innerHTML = x;
};function loadcontent4 () {
var x = document.getElementById("contentachievement").innerHTML;
contentoutput.innerHTML = x;
};


function init() {
 gameWorld.addEventHandlers()
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);
```

I tried writing it like this (did not work):

```
function loadcontent(contentid) {
    var x = document.getElementById(contentid).innerHTML;
    contentoutput.innerHTML = x;
}
```

And changed the event handler

```
    addEventHandlers : function() {
        linkhome.addEventListener("click", loadcontent("contenthome"));
        linkshop.addEventListener("click", loadcontent("contentshop"));
        ... 
    }
```

- Does anybody know why this did not work ?
- How can I make it work ?
- And as a side question: Why does `contentoutput.innerHTML` work without specifying `gameWorld.contentoutput`... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event handlers need an unexecuted function:

```
linkhome.addEventListener("click", function () { loadcontent("contenthome") });
```

By passing the argument you're actually executing the `loadcontent` function. And therefore the handler gets what the function returns instead of the function itself. To fix this, wrap `laodcontent("contenthome")`, for example, in a function expression so it can be fired by the click handler later.

Comment: Thank you ! This worked. Are there any links i can go to get more info about this behavior ?